# Confusion regarding quotient of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, invariant-theory

I am currently studying quotients of varieties, I use "Algebraic Geometry" by J. Harris. However, there are a few things I don't quite understand:

[image: p. 123]

1. (p. 123) At first it says that such a map $\pi$ is surjective, however in the second paragraph surjectivity is never mentioned. Is it not needed anymore? I found this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_quotient It looks suspiciously similar to the definition of Harris, and in the Wikipedia article it specifically mentions that $\pi$ does not necessarily have to be surjective. However, in Harris book, a few pages later he actually shows that a certain quotient map $\pi$ is surjective. That confuses me.

[image: p. 124]

2. (p. 124) The sentence starts on the first picture. I don't understand, what would be stupid about composing these two maps?

[image]

3. (p. 124) Here is an example where the quotient does not seem to exist. Here he also includes "surjective". But why does such a morphism not exist? Is it because the preimage of a closed subset has to be closed again under a morphism? In a variety with only two points $\{a, b\}$, where we identify $b = \mathbb{A} ^1 - \{0\}$, $b$ would be a closed point, however its preimage is open in  $\mathbb{A} ^1$. Does this explanation work? Or maybe is because: A morphism would be a polynomial $p$, which needs to satisfy $p(0) = a$ and $p(x) = b$ for all $x \neq 0$. But such a polynomial does not exist.

Please tell me if I said something wrong, I am stuck on this topic for a while now and I really want to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The continuous image of an irreducible space is irreducible.

Comment: A variety with two points is reducible, but the affine line is irreducible, so there exists no morphism, did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I believe that's the gist of Harris's example.

Comment: Does my explanation work, too? I don't think we have encountered irreducible spaces yet

Comment: Yes, the first one works - the preimages of the two points would have to be closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1$ by continuity. The second one needs a little bit more explanation but your idea is correct (namely, if one composes the putative morphism with an inclusion into $\mathbb{A}^1$, then the composition would be a polynomial with the property you describe). I wanted to mention the irreducibility argument because it's applicable in great generality.

Comment: Thank you very much!